# How to know if a phone number is a domestic number or international one

Tags: ruby-on-rails, phone-number, phonyrails

I am using PhonyRails (Phony) and I am trying to achieve the following:

If a domestic phone number is sent to me, I want to know whether its domestic or international. Why? Because if its domestic I want to convert it to the E164 standard.

How can I do this?

Comment: it seems that it depends on the country, may be in USA domestic form begins with specific number like 0, for Russia we have specified rule so all the phone number begins with 8 but then 10 if call to foreignt country, and else if domestic

Comment: Is there a lib that can assist me on that?

Comment: I dont know such lib %(

Answer (score 0):

If you are calling from the US, if the number starts with 011, then it's an international call. Other countries might start with different codes.